# How to find general term of ${a_{n}}$?

Tags: recurrence-relations

Suppose $a_{1}=a_{2}=\frac{1}{3}$, for $n = 3, 4, 5, ...$ , we have $$a_{n}=\frac{a_{n-1}^2(1−2a_{n-2})}{2a_{n-1}^2 − 4a_{n-2}a_{n-1}^2+a_{n-2}}$$

(1) Prove that $\frac{1}{a_{n}} −2$ are square numbers

(2) Find out the general term formula of ${a_{n}}$

I have done the first part using induction by assuming $x_n=\frac{1}{a_n} -2$, we get $$x_n=\frac{1}{x_{n-2}a_{n-1}^2}$$ on simplifying the relation but not able to solve to get general term, Can anyone suggest, how to proceed?

Comment: Use mathjax, please.

Comment: Thanks for editing using mathjax, I was not aware of this tool

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: *Suggestion:* Compute the first ten values, and see if you can find a pattern. Generally speaking, recurrences of this type have no closed form. Since you have been asked this, maybe the case given here is exceptional.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that $\big(\frac{1}{a_n}-2\big)^{1/2}$ is sequence [A001835](https://oeis.org/A001835) .  Can you prove this by induction?

Find everything you need to know there.  Many references.  And in particular
$$
\big(\frac{1}{a_n}-2\big)^{1/2}
= \frac{(3 + \sqrt3)^{2n - 1} + (3 - \sqrt3)^{2n - 1}}{6^n}
$$

Comment: yeah, this is sequence A001835, but how you reached here, want to know?

Comment: I did what I suggested in my comment.  Computed the first 10 terms, used your hint and computed $\big(\frac{1}{a_n}-2\big)^{1/2}$, then searched for that at OEIS.